# SQL - count and percent

Tags: sql, db2

hit a wall on getting a count AND a percentage of total in a single query

I want the TOTAL units per location AND the PERCENT of TOTAL ACROSS ALL LOCATIONS...

what I've got - is returning a 0 (zero) for percentage - I believe I have to cast the figure into a decimal or real type - but whatever i try (casting each element, or casting the whole result - i get errors...)

```
SELECT 
count(I.ID) as count
,L.ID
,(
    count(I.ID) 
    / 
    ( SELECT count(I2.ID) 
      FROM LOCATION L2
      JOIN ITEM I2 ON I2.LocID = L2.ID
      WHERE L2.ID IN (36,38,39,40) )
) AS percent
FROM LOCATION L
JOIN ITEM I ON I.LocID = L.ID
WHERE L.ID IN (36,38,39,40)
GROUP BY L.ID
```

Any thoughts on how to return a decimal???
or just make it more elegant .. period?

What I'd "expect"

```
ID      COUNT   PERCENT
2436    362     30.47
2438    184     15.48
2439    173     14.56
2440    172     14.47
2441    151     12.71
2442    54      4.54
2702    92      7.74
```

========
"t" suggested this - 
count(I.ID) * 100.0 / count(*) over () AS percent 
What is the "over()" supposed to do??

here's the return:

```
ID      COUNT   PERCENT
2436    362     51
2438    184     26
2439    173     24
2440    172     24
2441    151     21
2442    54      7
2702    92      13
```

========== SOLUTION

```
SELECT 
   count(I.ID) as count
   ,L.ID
   ,(
    1.0 * count(I.ID) / (
      SELECT count(I2.ID) 
      FROM LOCATION L2
      JOIN ITEM I2 ON I2.LocID = L2.ID
      WHERE L2.ID = L1.ID )
   ) * 100  AS percent
   FROM LOCATION L
   JOIN ITEM I ON I.LocID = L.ID
WHERE L.ID IN (36,38,39,40)
GROUP BY L.ID
```

Comment: I'm not a DB2 head, but with most languages/systems, if any one part of a division is a double/float, then floating division is performed. The simplest way to invoke that here would be to cast the count(I.ID) portion of the equation.

Comment: You can probably simplify your denominator as SELECT count(I2.ID) FROM ITEM I2 WHERE I2.LocID IN (36,38,39,40) - it should be a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply multiply by a float/decimal value

```
SELECT 
   count(I.ID) as count
   ,L.ID
   ,(
    100.0 * count(I.ID) 
    / 
     (
      SELECT count(I2.ID) 
      FROM LOCATION L2
      JOIN ITEM I2 ON I2.LocID = L2.ID
      WHERE L2.ID = L1.ID
     )
   ) AS percent
   FROM LOCATION L
   JOIN ITEM I ON I.LocID = L.ID

 WHERE L.ID IN (36,38,39,40)
 GROUP BY L.ID
```

Also, you'll need to consider a zero divisor giving "divide by zero" errors

Comment: THANKS gbn - super simple solution!!! I had to multiply by 100 - so my solution looked like this (1.0*count()/select)*100 AS percent...
pretty clean. much appreciated.

Comment: @jpmyob: you can multiply by 100.0 too to make it simpler. I should have done that first go. Answer updated

Answer (score 1):

First, check if your query works and returns the right values with:

```
SELECT 
count(I.ID) as count
,L.ID
,(SELECT count(I2.ID) 
      FROM LOCATION L2
      JOIN ITEM I2 ON I2.LocID = L2.ID
      WHERE L2.ID IN (36,38,39,40)
)
FROM LOCATION L
JOIN ITEM I ON I.LocID = L.ID
WHERE L.ID IN (36,38,39,40)
GROUP BY L.ID
```

Then use the [proper syntax](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref/castsp.htm) for DB2 casting:

```
CAST(%Expression% AS data-type)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ROUND()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_round.asp) function...

```
ROUND(..., 2) AS percent
```

Or just multiply by a decimal value (i.e. `1.0`). You also might want to include an `IF` or `CASE` (depending on your SQL server) to get around possible zero values

Comment: You should also be multiplying `count(I.ID)` by `100` to get a real percentage, not just a number that is less than one.